# Why does this pointer affectation raise an error?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, cs50, pointer-to-pointer

Recently started studying about pointers, I want to know why `char *n = “hii”; char *p = &n;` is showing the error `pointing to address`:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

int main(void)
   {
        char *n = "hii";
        /*why the below line is showing the error as it has no impact on the result, below the pointer p is pointing to address of n*/
        char *p = &n;
        printf("%i\n", &n);              
   }
```

Comment: You can't just sprinkle `&` around randomly.  You have to understand what it is actually doing, and when you actually need it.  `&` is an operator that constructs a pointer to something.  If you have a character, and you want a pointer to that character, you will need the `&` operator to do it.  But if you already have a pointer, and you just want to assign it to another pointer variable, you don't need the `&`.  So that line `char *p = &n;` is wrong.

Comment: Small point. "affectation" is typically referred to as "assignment" in English

Answer (score 5):

What's going on with this code is a mess:

```
int main(void)
{
  // initializes n to point to the string literal "hii". So far so good
  char *n = "hii";  
  // This is problem. It assigned the address of n (type char**) to p (type char*).
  // Your compiler should warn you about this.
  char *p = &n;
  // This is a problem. Trying to print the address of n (type char**) using the
  // %i format specifier, which is used for int types. To printf an address,
  // use the %p format specifier and cast the argument to void*.
  printf("%i\n", &n);
}
```

You can see all the warnings [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6PqoeGedc).  If you're compiler isn't producing these warnings, turn them on or use a better one.  Below is a "fix" of this code:

```
int main(void)
{
  // This is fine
  char *n = "hii";  
  // This assignment is valid since p and n are the same type (char*), and both
  // point to the string literal "hii"
  char *p = n;
  // This prints the _address_ of n
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&n);
  // This prints the address of where the string literal "hii" is stored
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  // these print the actual string
  printf("%s\n", n);
  printf("%s\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"char * p = & n;" is an error because the type of "&n" is "char **" not "char *", which the error you received from the compiler should have told you.

Comment: yes but i didn't understood what is going on this code clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of the type `T` where `T` is some type as for example

```
T n;
```

then a pointer to the object will look like

```
T *p = &n;
```

or that is the same

```
T ( *p ) = &n;
```

Now just imagine that the type `T` is defined as an alias for the type `char *`.

```
typedef char * T;
```

So substituting the alias for the defined type you will get

```
char *n;
char * ( *p ) = &n;
```

The last declaration can be rewritten like

```
char **p = &n;
```

So the compiler issues an error for this declaration

```
char *p = &n;
```

because the declared object has the type `char *` while the initializing expression has the type `char **` and there is no implicit conversion from the type `char **` to the type `char *`.

As for this declaration

```
char *n = "hii";
```

then the string literal `"hii"` has the type `char[4]` and internally is represented like `{ 'h', 'i', 'i', '\0' }`. Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. So the above declaration is equivalent to the following

```
char *n = &"hii"[0];
```

As for this call of `printf`

```
printf("%i\n", &n);
```

then it does not make a sense and has undefined behavior because there is used an incorrect conversion specifier with a pointer.

It seems you mean the following

```
printf( "%s\n", n );
```

or/and

```
printf( "%s\n", *p );
```

Or maybe

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )&n );
```

or

```
printf( "%ti\n", ( ptrdiff_t )&n );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *n = "hii";
    char * ( *p ) = &n;
    
    printf( "%s\n", n );
    printf( "%s\n", *p );
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )&n );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
hii
hii
0x7ffdf28b86d8
```